# Всплывающее окно (самописное или fancybox?)

Tags: jquery, fancybox, html, css, javascript

Стоит fancybox сейчас. Необходим плагин для формы подписки. При клике на ссылку - всплывающее окно с формой. 
Но не устраивает 2 фактора: скорость загрузки (грузит где-то секунд 6) и местоположение (всегда по центру (сильно не ковырялся, вроде перемещать нельзя)).
Вопрос следующий: будет ли эффективнее запихнуть форму подписки в display:none и при клике по ссылке с помощью  position: absolute выводить ее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У fancybox есть есть параметры topRatio и leftRatio от 0 до 1 ( по умолчанию 0.5 ), отвечающие за положение. 
Если у вас на сайте есть необходимость использовать fancybox только для нескольких всплывающих окон, то в таком случае можно написать небольшой скрипт, который будет это делать вместо плагина.
P.s. Сколько работал с fancybox, но чтоб 6 секунд грузился - никогда. Медленный интернет?

Comment: topRatio и leftRatio от 0 до 1 ( по умолчанию 0.5 )- это относительно окна браузера?
Можно относительно кликаемого объекта? И можно ли поменять прямоугольную форму выдачи на свой рисунок?

Comment: Относительно viewport'а. Относительно объекта не знаю как. Форму можно поменять через стили. Также есть возможность задать свой шаблон вывода fancybox через параметр tpl ( почитать можно тут http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ ).

Comment: Может долго грузит из-за того, что smart-responder сам по себе долгий? 
Fancybox открывает другую html страницу. Как ее можно заранее подгрузить?

Comment: По аяксу закгрузить html в невидимый блок, а потом при вызове fancybox указать этот блок.

Comment: Но тогда нагрузка упадет на главную? Что тоже не оч хорошо

Comment: Почему? Вы можете, к примеру, через пару секунд после загрузки страницы по аяксу подгрузить html. Визуально это никак не скажется.

Answer (score 1):

Да. Так будет эффективнее. Вот пример кода (я заменил файл slimbox.js на mootools на самописный lightbox на jQuery):

html:

```
<div class="custom-lightbox" style="display: none;">
    <a href="#" class="lightbox-close">X</a>
    <div class="lightbox-img-container"></div>
    <a href="#" class="lightbox-nav lightbox-nav-left"></a>
    <a href="#" class="lightbox-nav lightbox-nav-right"></a>
</div>

<div class="custom-lightbox-overlay" style="display: none;"></div>
```

js:

```
;
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var context = $('.gallery'),
            lightbox = $('.custom-lightbox'),
            overlay = $('.custom-lightbox-overlay'),
            container = $('.lightbox-img-container', lightbox),
            closeButton = $('.lightbox-close', lightbox),
            navLeft = $('.lightbox-nav-left', lightbox),
            navRight = $('.lightbox-nav-right', lightbox),
            currentLink = null,
            containerDimensions = {
                width: 0,
                height: 0
            };

        closeButton.click(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            hideLightbox();
            return false;
        });

        overlay.click(function () {
            hideLightbox();
        });

        function hideLightbox() {
            lightbox.fadeOut(1000, function () {
                overlay.hide();
            });         
        }

        $('.pagination-page a', context).click(function () {

            var href = $(this).attr('href'),                
                img = new Image();

            currentLink = $(this);
            img.src = href;

            img.onload = function () {
                lightbox.css({
                    'margin-left': parseInt(-(img.width / 2)),
                    'margin-top': parseInt(-(img.height / 2))
                });

                containerDimensions.width = parseInt(img.width);
                containerDimensions.height = parseInt(img.height);

                container.empty();
                container.append(img);

                overlay.show();
                lightbox.fadeIn(1000);
            }

            return false;
        });

        /* BUTTONS */
        navLeft.click(function () {

            var page = $('pagination-page:visible', context),
                current = currentLink,
                prev = current.prev(),
                href = prev.attr('href'),
                newImage = new Image();

            if (/jpg|jpeg|png|gif/.test(href)) {
                newImage.src = href;
                container.width(containerDimensions.width);
                container.height(containerDimensions.height);
                container.empty();              
            } else {
                return;
            }

            newImage.onload = function () {

                container.css({
                    'width': 'auto',
                    'height': 'auto'
                });

                lightbox.css({
                    'margin-left': parseInt(-(newImage.width / 2)),
                    'margin-top': parseInt(-(newImage.height / 2))
                });

                containerDimensions.width = parseInt(newImage.width);
                containerDimensions.height = parseInt(newImage.height);

                container.append(newImage);
                currentLink = prev;             
            }

        });

        navRight.click(function () {

            var current = currentLink,
                next = current.next(),
                href = next.attr('href'),
                newImage = new Image();

            if (/jpg|jpeg|png|gif/.test(href)) {
                newImage.src = href;
                container.width(containerDimensions.width);
                container.height(containerDimensions.height);
                container.empty();
            } else {
                return;
            }

            newImage.onload = function () {

                container.css({
                    'width': 'auto',
                    'height': 'auto'
                });

                lightbox.css({
                    'margin-left': parseInt(-(newImage.width / 2)),
                    'margin-top': parseInt(-(newImage.height / 2))
                });

                containerDimensions.width = parseInt(newImage.width);
                containerDimensions.height = parseInt(newImage.height);

                container.append(newImage);
                currentLink = next;
            }

        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

В случае с формой все гораздо проще.